# partial cloning of List<T> using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

i have a List that have some properties e.g.

```
public Class Person 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses {get;set}
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } 
}

public class Address
{
    public string StreeNo { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map it to a dynamic object that should not have CreatedOn and CreatedBy automapper, i have seen an example using

```
public static List<T> MapDynamicList<T>(IEnumerable<object> obj)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var newModel = obj.Select(mapper.Map<T>).ToList();

    return newModel;
}
```

but this maps with same properties as of source  where as i dont want CreatedOn and CreatedBy to be copied in destination

Reason behind all this i m trying to create a viewmodel without mentioned properties as my all classes have CreatedOn Created By and to manually create viewmodel for every one is quite difficult as classes gets updated.

any help will be apprecited

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need these properties in your destination, then just create viewmodel, that has no such properties :)

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string StreeNo { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
}

public Class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel[] Addresses { get; set; }
}

// Automapper profile
CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel();
CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();

// Usage
var personViewModelList = MapDynamicList<PersonViewModel>(persons);
```

You may also use Automapper `.Ignore()`, but solution with explicit ViewModel classes seems to be more clear.

By the way, you don't need to use LINQ .Select to map `IEnumerable`, Automapper can map collections, so instead of this:

```
var newModel = obj.Select(mapper.Map<T>).ToList();
```

You can just do this:

```
var newModel = mapper.Map<List<T>>(obj);
```

This will map every object to `T`, and then place them into a list.